# Como usar jquery em uma diretiva angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Tentei colocar uma função em jQuery dentro de uma diretiva, mas não está funcionando.
Pesquisei e achei em vários lugares falando sobre jqLite, mas não soube converter o jQuery para jqLite.

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).tooltip('hide')
});

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on("click", function () {
    $(this).tooltip('hide')
});
```

Comment: Você já tem o jquery instalado na sua aplicação?

Comment: Sim! preciso encapsular esse código na diretiva, mas não estou sabendo como fazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module("components").directive("clearTooltip", function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).tooltip("hide");
      });

      element.on("click", function () {
        $(this).tooltip("hide");
      });
      element.addClass("teste");
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso jquery em algumas directivas do angularjs e funciona perfeitamente. Da uma olhada em um exemplo que tenho aqui:

```
app.directive("scrollToTopButton", function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).addClass('scrollToTop');

        $(window).on("scroll", function () {
            if (this.pageYOffset > 300) {
                $(element).fadeIn();
            }
            if (this.pageYOffset <= 0) {
                $(element).fadeOut();
            }
        });

        element.on("click", function () {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 800);

            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Está basicamente a mesma coisa do meu, mas não está funcionando.